# How to list all the File accessed by a process? (also released)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, debug, xperf

I'm trying to get a list of files accessed by a specific process by having either its process ID or by launching it under some command line utility.

I tried `xperf` but the documentation is really vague and despite a day of attempts, I can't get what I need.

Is anybody aware of such utility?

Note: The list of accessed file should include also the file that have been opened and closed.

Comment: You can use a combination of Powershell and [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). See [Get-OpenFile](http://msgoodies.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/get-openfile.html) for a starting point.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I considered this but I think that with this approach I may loose some information, for example if a file is for example opened very briefly I may not be able to capture it

Answer (score 1):

I know [Process Monitor 3.2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) will do what you want, but it is known primarily as GUI based tool. If you type `procmon /?`, you get a list of command line options. My suggestion would be to export a configuration (.pmf) and use it to export a CSV or XML file for analysis.

Unfortunately, having to create a configuration file beforehand does not allow you to just type the name of the process you want to follow. You can [automate writing of filters](http://nomanualrequired.blogspot.com/2013/04/automating-process-monitor.html), but requires you to use PowerShell.

[image]

Comment: Seems promising. Will try it